# Simple NSOperationQueue ends in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c

```
NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = ^{NSLog(@"This is an NSBlockOperation");};
NSOperationQueue *ownQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[ownQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];        
[ownQueue addOperation:blockOperation];
```

I am just trying out `NSBlockOperation`, however this simple code ends with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.
The code is in main and surrounded by `@autorelease`.

```
libsystem_c.dylib`OSAtomicCompareAndSwapIntBarrier$VARIANT$mp:
0x7fff8b8dc524:  movl   %edi, %eax

libsystem_c.dylib`OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32$VARIANT$mp + 2:

0x7fff8b8dc526:  lock   
0x7fff8b8dc527:  cmpxchgl%esi, (%rdx)
0x7fff8b8dc52a:  sete   %al
0x7fff8b8dc52d:  movzbl %al, %eax
0x7fff8b8dc530:  ret    
0x7fff8b8dc531:  nopl   (%rax)
```

The Program stops and points at `0x7fff8b8dc526:  lock`

Comment: Did you try copying the block? Blocks are created on the stack and if your async methods return, it's invalidated. By copying it, you move it to the heap.

Comment: Do you mean: [ownQueue addOperation:[blockOperation copy]]. This results in the same error.

Comment: my whole code really is just the main method with @autorelease and those 4 lines of code within them (plus return (0) obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to assign a block to a `NSBlockOperation`, but that are different types. Correct is

```
NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"This is an NSBlockOperation");
}];
```